# Rock,Paper,Scissors With Bot, Why Is My program Not printing out any answers Even When I defined bot move using ‘’s?

Tags: python

In my code I did a whole lot of if statements I know that It’s a lot but that was the only way I could think of But It first said Botmove not defined then I addded the ’’s but Now it’s not printing anything for example, I did y then, r but nothing appears. can Anyone help me? Also Here’s My code:

```
random=random.randint(1,3)
if random==1:
  botmove='r'
if random==2:
  botmove='p'
if random==3:
  botmove='s'


print('Play Rock,Paper,Scissors?')
print('Y/N')
play=input('>').lower().strip()
if play=='n':
  print('Thank You For Playing.')
if play=='y':
  print('Rock Or Paper Or Scissors?')
  print('R/P/S')
  move=input('>').strip().lower()
  
  #code
  if move=='r':
    if botmove=='r':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('Draw.')
    if botmove=='p':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('You Lost.')
    if botmove=='s':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('You Won.')
  if move=='p':
    if botmove=='r':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('You Won.')
    if botmove=='p':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('Draw.')
    if botmove=='s':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('You Lost.')
  if move=='s':
    if botmove=='r':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('You Lost.')
    if botmove=='p':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('You Won.')
    if botmove=='s':
      print('The Computer Chose:',botmove)
      print('Draw.')
```

Edit: Thank Everyone For Helping!

Comment: The intent of some stuff here is unclear. `'botmove'=='r'` should surely be `botmove = 'r'`. The `'`s mean you're indicating a string, not the name of a variable, and `==` is for equality checking, not assignment.

Comment: I want to make perfectly sure I understand how you are thinking about the code. Where you have written `'botmove'=='r'` on a line by itself near the beginning of the code, your belief is that this creates a variable named `botmove`, and assigns the value `'r'` to it? Or exactly what do you think happens there? And when you write `if 'botmove'=='p':`, your expectation is that this will check whether your variable named `botmove` has that value? (Hint: on the immediately previous - and correct - line of code `if move=='r':`, why did you *not* write `if 'move'=='r':`?)

Comment: "But It first said Botmove not defined" Well, yes. Presumably you previously had the code `botmove=='r'`, and were expecting that to define the variable, and you found that it wasn't defined that way; so you changed it to `'botmove'=='r'`. But *what was your underlying reasoning for that change*?

Comment: You need to follow a Python tutorial and practice more; and pay more attention and think more clearly. Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn the language fundamentals.

Comment: 2 suggestions. (1) you have 3 `if move == 'r'` statements (for example). The code would be a little simpler with **one** outer `if move == r` statement. Then after the first `if 'botmove' == 'p'` use `elif botmove == 'r'...` As writen the code will work, but it's shorter with elif. (2) You should add extra print statement(s) to tell the human player what the computer played.

Comment: My reason to put ‘’s around bot move was because it gave u an error when it ran it… I’m sorry If I was Confused 

Comment: It says bot move Not defined How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `botmove` is a variable, you should not put it inside quotes because that turns it into a string.

Moreover, `botmove == 'r'` is incorrect when you are assigning `r` to `botmove`. because `==` is a comparison operator. So you have to replace that with `=` instead to assign the `botmove` variable to `r`

And, you could replace:

```
if move=='r':
    if botmove =='p':
        print('You Lost.')
if move=='r':
    if botmove =='r':
        print('Draw.')
if move=='r':
    if botmove =='s':
        print('You Won.')
```

with:

```
  if move=='r':
      if botmove =='p':
          print('You Lost.')
      if botmove =='r':
          print('Draw.')
      if botmove =='s':
          print('You Won.')
```

Also, instead of `random.randrange`, you could use `random.randint` to return an integer. However, you should pass (1,3) instead of (1,4)

So, Finally your code should look something like this:

```
import random

random=random.randint(1,3)
if random==1:
   botmove ='r'
if random==2:
   botmove ='p'
if random==3:
   botmove ='s'


print('Play Rock,Paper,Scissors?')
print('Y/N')
play=input('>').lower().strip()
if play=='n':
    print('Thank You For Playing.')
if play=='y':
    print('Rock Or Paper Or Scissors?')
    print('R/P/S')
    move=input('>').strip().lower()
    if move=='r':
        if botmove=='p':
            print('You Lost.')
        if botmove=='r':
            print('Draw.')
        if botmove=='s':
            print('You Won.')

‘’’
```